# Detect if Flex AdvancedDataGrid itemClick is actually a drag

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

Is there any way to detect if AdvancedDataGrid itemClick event is actually caused by the user dragging? I'd like to take action on click, but ignore drag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add drag handler, dispatch new click event for the same target and kill drag event or stop it.

or just use standard click event